# How to diagnose suddenly failing grub boot from iso?

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

I have had my Ubuntu 18.04 system set up to optionally boot off several .iso files (the .iso files are stored on a different hard drive from /) and it's been working for a long time.  I set it up using instructions on the Ubuntu wiki [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot). It worked well, I make Clonezilla backups, etc using this feature.

Recently, though, I tried to make a Clonezilla backup and the .iso wouldn't boot. I got an error message saying that it couldn't find the .iso. I checked and the .iso is still there in the same old spot.  Testing showed that none of the .isos will boot any more.

I have made no hardware changes nor have I moved any of the .iso files.

I know there have been 2 updates to grub so far this year.

What is the suggested procedure for troubleshooting this problem?  Since I didn't (knowingly at least) change anything, I am at a loss as to where to start.  I compared the scripts in /etc/grub.d with the ones from a clean install, and I saw only the changes I had made.   Did the updates to grub remove this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As so often happens, after giving up and posting a question, I figured it out.

This part of my question was incorrect: "I have made no hardware changes...."

There was an Android tablet plugged into a USB port, and the UEFI was counting it as the first drive.

This messed up the drive count and my `hd0,1` was not what I expected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) I think it can help several people in similar situations.