# Ubuntu doesn't start when hard drive is plugged in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive

About a week ago i was tinkerin around and created a bootable linux drive on an USB. I was able to switch to the usb and back to windows without any problems. But after some time neither linux nor windows would boot from any of the drives.
After that I decided to fully fully wipe my main drive (also deleting windows" and start fresh with a ubuntu installation. After booting into it for the first time I had some weird resolution problems, so I just decided to reinstall freshly again. After a fresh installation I couldn't boot into linux tho and grub wouldn't start, I just got a black screen.
After that I decided to unplug my second harddrive reboot my pc. Magicly, ubuntu started. I don't know why the harddrive cause problems tho, because it was only used for storage before...
How can fix the problem, so I can have my harddrive plugged in and still boot into linux?

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1118405/243321

Comment: Enter your computer's BIOS with and without hdd and mention difference in boot menu. Probably you need to specify correctly boot device in BIOS.

Comment: Run `gparted` on your unmounted disk, and clear the `BOOT` flag from any partition that it has it set. When the `BOOT` flag it set, the BIOS will try to boot from it, if it's the first disk seen. If there's nothing there, the BIOS tries anyhow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)